# Open Splunk forwarder/receiver TCP port on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, splunk

I need to open TCP port 9997 on OpenShift so Splunk is able to listen for incoming data from fowarders on other servers.

I've set up Splunk using this guide: http://www.kelvinism.com/2013/11/free-splunk-hosting.html and but I can't figure out how to add another TCP port to the manifest.yml file. I tried the following for a new OpenShift instance but with no luck.

```
  - Private-IP-Name:   IP
    Private-Port-Name: PORT_FORWARDER
    Private-Port:      9997
    Public-Port-Name:  PROXY_PORT_FORWARDER
    Options:           { "ssl_to_gear": true }
```

Do I need to configure other parts of the cartridge to read my new port and set up some configuration elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be able to listen publicly on ports 80/443/8000/8443, no other tcp or udp ports are allowed in (except 22 for ssh/scp/sftp).  The private port that you have configured is for internal access only (either on the same gear, or installed on it's own gear as part of a scaled application).  Having remote agents connect to your application on port 9997 just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can write a very simple splunk add-on to listen on that port, that's very straight forward.
Splunk has a SDK you can implement it with variable language. Here is a framework for python. for more information, you can see a full example for UDP receiver: [link to the example](http://matthewgao.github.io/howtowritesplunkplugin/), it's not an english post, but you can read the code from there.

```
import sys

from splunklib.modularinput import *

class MyScript(Script):

    def get_scheme(self):
        # Returns scheme.

    def validate_input(self, validation_definition):
        # Validates input.

    def stream_events(self, inputs, ew):
        # Splunk Enterprise calls the modular input, 
        # streams XML describing the inputs to stdin,
        # and waits for XML on stdout describing events.

        # TODO: implement a socket to listen and receive the 
        # message then send by Event()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(MyScript().run(sys.argv))
```